# Run Stored Procedure From Another Database in Current Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have one `shared` database and multiple `client` databases.  The data is stored in the `client` database.  We want to create a master set of stored procedures in the `shared` database and execute them from the `client` database.  Given the following:

```
use shared;
go
create procedure GetInvoices as
  print db_name() ' <- current database'
  select * from invoices
go

use client1;
create table invoices(...columns...)
exec shared.dbo.GetInvoices
```

This returns the following error:

```
shared <- current database
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetInvoices, Line 3
Invalid object name 'invoices'.
```

**Without** using dynamic SQL, how can I run the stored procedure in `shared` from `client1` so that it executes in `client1` and thus has access to all of the tables in `client1`?

Comment: I suspect this is impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a stored procedure defined in `master` database in context of `client1` database and *see all client1 database tables*, **without** dynamic SQL, but it uses *undocumented* stored procedure `sp_ms_marksystemobject`.

Your stored procedure name must start with `sp_`, for example `sp_GetInvoices`. Create it in `master` database, then call `exec sp_ms_marksystemobject sp_GetInvoices` to make it see the tables of the current database.

```
USE master
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetInvoices  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ClientName from Invoice
END
GO

exec sp_ms_marksystemobject sp_GetInvoices

USE client1
GO

create table Invoice (ClientName varchar(100))
insert Invoice select 'Acme Client'

exec sp_GetInvoices
```

Result (running on SQL Server version 13.0.5081.1):

```
ClientName
------------ 
Acme Client
```

Comment: It's amazing how easy it is when you know the undocumented features.  Thank you, sincerely!

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your "Master" database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDataFromClient]
    @DB VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @STMT VARCHAR( 300 );
DECLARE @SP VARCHAR( 500 );


SET @SP = 'dbo.GetData';


SET @STMT = 'EXEC(''' +  @SP + ''')';   


EXEC('USE '+ @db + ';' + @STMT)

END
```

Now on the "Client" database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestClient](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](10) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)   WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY].
```

Create the stored procedure to retrieve data from table TestClient

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM TestClient;

END
```

Now you can retrieve the columns from the TestClient Database using:

```
USE [TestMaster]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[GetDataFromClient]
     @DB = N'TESTCLIENT'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call stored procedure using four part name after creating link server.
Or it can be called by openquery option.

LinkSerevr:

EXEC [ServerName] .dbname.scheme.StoredProcedureName

openquery : SELECT * FROM 
OPENQUERY( [ServerName] .dbname.scheme.StoredProcedureName)

Comment: He wants to execute stored proc from another database but wants it to deal with data in current database.

Comment: add stored proc in model database

Comment: Adding to model doesn't help.  Adding to master is one step closer but still doesn't help.  When created in master with `sp_` at the front of the proc name, you can run it from the `client1` database without fully qualifying the stored procedure name.  Then `print db_name()` shows `client1`, but it still says `invoices` is not found.  So even though the database context is right, it still looks in master for the tables instead of the client database.